# Importing GitHub Project (eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, github, import, project

I'm trying to import a github project into eclipse https://github.com/KolakCC/lol-jclient, but I end up with a bunch of errors because it can't find imports to the stuff in the libs folder. How do make eclipse recognize where the libs folder is and fix the imports? thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

That repo [KolakCC/lol-jclient](https://github.com/KolakCC/lol-jclient) has no `.classpath` and no `.project`.

So you need, once imported into an Eclipse project, add the lib folder in the classpath of that project yourself.
See for instance: "[FAQ How do I add an extra library to my project's classpath?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath?)", with selecting `Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries` (also illustrated in "[How to put a jar in classpath in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11463590/6309)").

Or you can add a lib directly on the build path:

[image: http://pad3.whstatic.com/images/thumb/7/70/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29-Step-4.jpg/670px-Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29-Step-4.jpg]

(as detailed in "[Eclipse: Adding all the jars from a folder in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12266998/6309)")

The [OP Gratin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2263418/gratin) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103716/importing-github-project-eclipse/24103750?noredirect=1#comment37181625_24103750):

> got it to work by adding as src folder and adding all the jar.

Comment: @Gratin I just added another way to add those libs to your build path.

Comment: Wait it doesn't work because if you take a look at the lib folder in that github project, they're not just jar files O.o

Comment: @Gratin true. Add the libs (jars) that you can find, and see if that is enough. If not, you might have to compile/build the jars within the folders where there are only sources for those libs.

Comment: thanks got it to work by adding as src folder and adding all the jars :)

Comment: @Gratin great. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.